# how do i find outlook 2010 missing subfolder and emails?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-outlook-2010

One of my subfolders under my Inbox is missing and when I use the "search all mailboxes" feature to find emails I know are in there they don't show. Only items in the sent folder or other folders show.
I'm using Outlook 2010. Windows 8.

Comment: Please don't think this as being a rude comment or stating the obvious, but some times we can all miss little things, but can you confirm your inbox or any subolders isn't closed (and the folder is therefore hidden). Also check the deleted folder

Comment: You could use the Outlook search window on the top right. Enter a sender name of a missing mail and hit return. Outlook will either find the mail or offer to search "all e-mails". This search includes nested sub-folders and should be helpful in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry, with my rep, I can't post a comment yet, but the first thing I would do is look at your OWA access (if it's an exchange email) to see if the folder is even there.  Or you can login to your web interface (in the case of gmail or alike).  If it is your gmail (or a similar account) did you use IMAP or POP3 to link it to the Outlook?  If it's IMAP, than (unless the folder was deleted and the trash was emptied) you will like see it in your email upon web login.  Hope this helps.